# Docker build not using cache for reactjs project using yarn

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile

```
# Base on offical Node.js Alpine image
FROM node:16-alpine3.14

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/app

# Install PM2 globally
RUN npm install --global pm2

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json before other files
# Utilise Docker cache to save re-installing dependencies if unchanged
COPY ./package.json ./

COPY ./yarn.lock ./

# Install dependencies
RUN yarn install

# Copy all files
COPY ./ ./

# Build app
RUN yarn build

# Expose the listening port
EXPOSE 3000

# Run container as non-root (unprivileged) user
# The node user is provided in the Node.js Alpine base image
USER node

# Run npm start script when container starts
# CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

CMD [ "pm2-runtime", "npm", "--", "start" ]
```

I am trying to build the image

```
docker build -t test .
```

After first time building I am trying to build again. without any change in the context.

I see it uses cache till some extent only. and and after that it does not use cache

```
# Install dependencies
RUN yarn install
```

[image]

HOw to make it use cache if there is no changes in the code.

Comment: can you add more details on the changes you've made and the output you're getting in the terminal?

Comment: I didnt make any changes in the project files.

Comment: so please just add the output you're seeing

Comment: added the image with output

Comment: OK, first you didn't reiterate the dependency installation but the project compilation part. when running `yarn build` you're taking your project and compiling it down to servable files. so far so good?

Comment: so why its not using the cache

Comment: have you made changes to the Dockerfile that are unrelated?